# Cannot use gnomesu on Debian Linux on a Chromebook

Tags: gnome, root

I am using an Acer Chromebook with an Intel processor. Chrome OS version 103.0.5060.132 (Official Build) (64-bit). I successfully installed Linux (beta).
In the Linux virtual machine, already ran:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

The installation was successful. But then when I type:

```
gnomesu nautilus
```

(or anything with gnomesu)
I get the following error:

```
bash: gnomesu: command not found.
```

I searched on Google for an answer, but no results showed up. I'm surprised that no one has the same issue that I have.
What do I need to install for that to work?

Comment: "command not found" is self-explanatory. If you don't have that command you must install it first. Google is your friend.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package gnomesu